# Can I analytically integrate a high dimensional Normal distribution?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, statistics

Let's say $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. If I have two half spaces: $H_{1} = \{x: a^{T}x \geq 0\}, H_{2} = \{x: b^{T}x \geq 0\}$, is there a way I can compute the total probability mass in the area $H_{1} \cap H_{2}$?

Comment: In general no. You can when you have a special type of geometry, so for instance, the half-spaces form a cone, and you use spherical coordinates to nicely describe that region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $a = \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3}$ and $b = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}$ and

$$M:= \pmatrix{a&b}=\pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\\a_3&b_3}$$
Denote
$Y = \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} =  M^T\cdot X \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $Y\sim\mathcal{N}_2\left(M\mu,M\cdot\Sigma \cdot M^T  \right)$ a bivariate normal distribution.
We have
$$H_1 \cap H_2 = \{y_1 \ge 0,y_2 \ge 0  \}$$
Then
$$\color{red}{P=\Phi_2\left(\pmatrix{0\\0},\pmatrix{+\infty\\+\infty};  M\mu,M\cdot\Sigma \cdot M^T \right)}$$
where $\Phi_2\left(\mathbf{l},\mathbf{u};  \text{mean},\text{covariance}\right)$ is the culmulative distribution function of a bivariate normal distribtution.